# Swift / How to set (and load) a new root view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a RootVC. It is a `SwipeViewController: UINavigationController`.

[SwipeViewController](https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20swipeviewcontroll)

Within `WelcomeNavigationController`, I'm checking a condition. If that condition is true, I want to open the RootVC.

```
class WelcomeNavigationController: UINavigationController { 

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        backendless.userService.setStayLoggedIn(true)

    if backendless.userService.currentUser != nil {

        print("currentUser != nil")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc : RootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootVC") as! RootVC
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
            appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    }
}
```

The print statement is executed and some print statements from my RootVC are executed as well. So in theory the RootVC is loaded. But it is not visible. How can I make my RootVC visible?

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be add rootVC to current view controller

```
self.addChildViewController(vc)
vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: `vc.didMoveToParentViewController:self` throws error = Expected expression

Comment: `(self)` solved it. But it doesn't work for me. It's the same than before, but with a white navigation bar on top. The "old" view seems to be frozen. And print statements from my `RootVC` are executed.

Comment: ah, my experiment in this case. you should push from welcomeViewController -> rootVC .
After that remove welcomeVC in navigationController.viewControllers.
And set rootVC to rootViewController

Comment: I was able to solve it with your help. Thank you for your effort